# pySpark DataFrame: how to parallelize compare the columns of two dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two DataFrames, and I want to apply `distance.euclidean(df1.select(col),df2.select(col))` for each column of the two DataFrame.

Example:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df1 = spark.createDataFrame([(1,10),(2,13)],["A","B"])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([(3,40),(2,20)],["A","B"])

# Apply distance function for each columns of `df1` and `df2`
from scipy.spatial import distance
for col in df1.columns:
    d = distance.euclidean(df1.select(col).rdd.flatMap(lambda x:x).collect(), df2.select(col).rdd.flatMap(lambda x:x).collect())
    print(col,d)
```

The numbers of columns is large, about `5,000`. Is there any method calculate the `distance` of the columns in parallel instead of calculating one by one using `for` function.

Comment: Do you have only two rows or is it just for this example?

Comment: This is just an example, actually about `5000` columns in the two `DataFrame`s.

Comment: I asked about `rows`.

Comment: Emm, there are many `rows`, otherwise I don't need to use `spark`.

Comment: Is there an index column which allows ordering or a mapping between the two dataframe rows?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry to ignore that. There are a column named `id` for joining or mapping.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no built-in euclidean distance function, but you can easily build one with [sum](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/sql/#sum), [pow](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/sql/#pow), [sqrt](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/sql/#sqrt) as the equation is pretty simple:

[image: euclidean distance equation]

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 10, 1),(2, 13, 2), (3, 5, 3)], ["A", "B", "id"])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([(3, 40, 1),(2, 20, 2), (3, 10, 3)],["A", "B", "id"])

df1 = df1.alias("df1")
df2 = df2.alias("df2")

df = df1.join(df2, 'id', 'inner')
df.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
| id|  A|  B|  A|  B|
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  1| 10|  3| 40|
|  3|  3|  5|  3| 10|
|  2|  2| 13|  2| 20|
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

```py
expression = ['sqrt(sum(pow((df1.{col} - df2.{col}),2))) as {col}'.format(col=c) for c in df1.columns if c !='id']
print(expression)
df.selectExpr(expression).show()
```

Output:

```
['sqrt(sum(pow((df1.A - df2.A),2))) as A', 'sqrt(sum(pow((df1.B - df2.B),2))) as B']
+---+-----------------+
|  A|                B|
+---+-----------------+
|2.0|31.20897306865447|
+---+-----------------+
```

P.S.: [collect](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.collect) should only be used when the dataframe is small, as all the data is loaded into the memory of your spark driver.

Comment: Hi, something run wrong with error `'\nno viable alternative at input ` .

Comment: @rosefun Can you please add the full error stacktrace to your question? You are maybe missing a column, but I can't tell for sure without the full error message.